# List comprehension with *args

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, iteration, list-comprehension

I would like to write a function to return a set of strings using python´s list comprehension if any of the passed arguments is in the list. However, it throws *requires string as left operand, not tuple*, and when trying with another for loop it throws *local variable j referenced before assignment*

```
def checkFor(*args):
    return {a['title'] for a in soup.findAll('a') if 'title' in a.attrs and any(args in a['title'])}

def checkFor_(*args):
    return{a['href'] for a in soup.findAll('a') if 'title' in a.attrs and j in a['title'] for i, j in enumerate(args)}

checkFor(a, b, c)
```

Ï could surely do it with for loops but I am trying to use list comprehension. Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
def checkFor(*args):
    return {a['title'] for a in soup.findAll('a') if 'title' in a.attrs and any(arg in a['title'] for arg in args)}
```

You're just missing one more `for` to expand the tuple `args` into its elements.

Comment: Ah, perfect!! Nice and concise! Thanks!