# When should I use *args?

Tags: python, function, arguments

When writing Python 3.x functions, I've often stumbled upon the problem of writing code that accepts both a single value and a number of values.
Take this trivial function:

```
def capitalize(word):
    return word.capitalize()
```

This function works well with a single string as input, but will fail if provided with multiple strings, or a list of strings.

We could turn the function to accept a list of strings, that way it would work if provided both with one value, or multiple. Even if I passed a single value, however, it would need to be wrapped in a list, and the return value would be a list as well, even when containing one element.

```
def capitalize(words):
    return [word.capitalize() for word in words]
```

I recently read up on *args, and thought i could get around the awkwardness of having to pass a single string wrapped in a list as argument to the above function by rewriting it to be like the following:

```
def capitalize(*words):
    return [word.capitalize() for word in words]
```

It seems to me that this is a legittimate use of `*args`. However, I found a pyCon 2015 talk in which the speaker claims "variable positional arguments are good for removing noise and make your code readable, not to turn a single call api into an N api"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjJUPxKB164 at the 5:30 mark.

Is this a reasonable use of *args? If this is not how `*args` is supposed to be used, is there an established way to handle single vs multi-parameter functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List comprehension with \*args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332957/list-comprehension-with-args)

Comment: I watched for about 2 minutes before the 5:30 mark and I'm not sure what the speaker is trying to say. He's actually pretty much demonstrating your exact use case there, so… yes, this is fine.

Comment: Your solution seems fine, although I'm surprised you say you see this *often*, I think this is pretty rare. Also, note if you're actually trying to capitalize all words in a sentence, use `str.title()`

Comment: You can use *words for more readablity.

Comment: @deceze I was also a bit confused by the statement he made, which seems to contradict what he's shown in the code. hence my question.

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion based...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's fine to use `*args` here.

You should use `*args` when it's easier to read than a list of argument (`def foo(a,b,c,d,e...)`) and does not make harder to know which argument is used for what.

Your example is the perfect example of a good usage of `*args`, all elements within `args` will be processed in the exacte same way.

You should avoid it when you need to perform different compute for each argument, like:

```
def foo(*args):
     do_one_stuff(args[1], args[2])
     if args[3]:
         do_another_stuff(args[3], args[4])
     if args[6] != args[7]:
         return args[0]
     else:
         return None
```

This example should make you feel what a function could be if you make a bad usage of `*args`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the accepted answer (which raises some good points), you also have to consider how your function is going to be used. Using `os.path.join` as an example, it makes sense for this function to accept `*args` because one is going to often be dealing with a set number of path elements, where each one might have its own name. For example:

```
dir_name = os.getcwd()
temp_folder = 'temp'
base_name = 'base_file.txt'
full_path = os.path.join(dir_name, temp_folder, base_name)
```

On the other hand, when you are working with indistinguishable elements that are naturally going to be grouped into a container object, it makes more sense to use `args`. Consider the following usage with `str.join`.

```
sentence = 'this is an example sentence'
words = sentence.split()
dash_separated = '-'.join(words)
```

Answer (score 2):

*args combine the extra positional arguments into a tuple so you can handle them inside your function. This is **optional**. The required parameters inside your function preferbly be positional args, in that case you will get an error in your IDE when calling it without these parameters.

*args can be used as an extension, and for future development without breaking old implementations.

```
# required args
def test_req(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print arg1, arg2, arg3


# not required
def test_args(*args):
    if args:
        print args, type(args)
        for arg in args:
            print arg

test_req(1, 2, 3)
test_args(1, 2, 3)
```

Output

```
1 2 3
(1, 2, 3) <type 'tuple'>
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: it depends.

In python `*args` is used to pass an **unknown** number of arguments to a function. Quite similarly to calling `printf()` in C which accepts an unknown number of arguments.

So, if you do not know beforehand how many arguments user would like to process using `*args` is a solution. What I think was the intention of the speaker was not to use this feature **unless** we do not know the number of arguments. So if you'd like to compare two arguments you'd use:

```
def names_are_equal(name1, name2):
    return name1 == name2
```

and not

```
def names_are_equal(*names):
    return names[0] == names[1]
```

On the other hand if you'd like to, say, capitalize an unknown number of names you'd use:

```
def capitalize_names(*names):
    return [name.upper() for name in names]
```

Note that using `*` can be handy in other situations like unpacking arguments:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a, *b, c = l
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3, 4]
>>> c
5
```

Answer (score -1):

**`*args`** is the special parameter which can take 0 or more (positional) arguments as a tuple. *In Python, there are 2 kinds of arguments [**positional argument and keyword argument**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters-in-p/74406075#74406075) explains about **`**kwargs`**:

For example, `*args` can take 0 or more arguments as a tuple as shown below:

```py
           ↓
def test(*args):
    print(args)

test() # Here
test(1, 2, 3, 4) # Here
test((1, 2, 3, 4)) # Here
test(*(1, 2, 3, 4)) # Here
```

Output:

```
()
(1, 2, 3, 4)
((1, 2, 3, 4),)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

And, when printing `*args`, 4 numbers are printed without parentheses and commas:

```py
def test(*args):
    print(*args) # Here
 
test(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
```

And, `args` has **tuple** type:

```py
def test(*args):
    print(type(args)) # Here
 
test(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Output:

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

But, `*args` has no type:

```py
def test(*args):
    print(type(*args)) # Here
 
test(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Output(Error):

> TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments

And, normal parameters can be put before `*args` as shown below:

```py
          ↓     ↓
def test(num1, num2, *args):
    print(num1, num2, args)
    
test(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Output:

```
1 2 (3, 4)
```

But, `**kwargs` cannot be put before `*args` as shown below:

```py
             ↓     
def test(**kwargs, *args):
    print(kwargs, args)
    
test(num1=1, num2=2, 3, 4)
```

Output(Error):

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

And, normal parameters cannot be put after `*args` as shown below:

```py
                 ↓     ↓
def test(*args, num1, num2):
    print(args, num1, num2)
    
test(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Output(Error):

> TypeError: test() missing 2 required keyword-only arguments: 'num1' and 'num2'

But, if normal parameters have default values, they can be put after `*args` as shown below:

```py
                      ↓         ↓
def test(*args, num1=100, num2=None):
    print(args, num1, num2)
    
test(1, 2, num1=3, num2=4)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2) 3 4
```

And also, `**kwargs` can be put after `*args` as shown below:

```py
                    ↓
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    
test(1, 2, num1=3, num2=4)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2) {'num1': 3, 'num2': 4}
```

Actually, you can use other names for `*args` and `**kwargs` as shown below. `*args` and `**kwargs` are used conventionally:

```py
            ↓        ↓
def test(*banana, **orange):
    print(banana, orange)
    
test(1, 2, num1=3, num2=4)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2) {'num1': 3, 'num2': 4}
```